# whatever_two.on_press_button() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

Tags: python, kivy

Here's the code I'm working with:

#### Python

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
#from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from numpy import spacing
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
#all the libraries

BlueBackground = (71, 161, 221, 0)
red = [1, 0, 0, 1]
green = [0, 1, 0, 1]
blue = [0, 0, 1, 1]
purple = [1, 0, 1, 1]

RESOURCEPATH = 'C:\\Users\\me\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\\AppLockManager\\Resources\\'
LAYOUTS = 'C:\\Users\\me\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\\AppLockManager\\Layouts\\'

Builder.load_file(LAYOUTS + 'Button.kv')
#here i load the whatever file that is in the bottom
Builder.load_file(LAYOUTS + 'whatever.kv')


Window.size = (400, 600)
Window.clearcolor = BlueBackground

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return whatever_two()


class whatever_two(Widget):

    def on_press_button(self, instance):
        print("You clicked the button " + instance.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Here is the .kv file for the `whatever_two` the file is named `whatever`

```
#:kivy 1.0
<whatever_two>   
    GridLayout:
        size: root.size
        cols: 2
        rows: 1
        Label:
            text: 'Hello world'
            font_size: 50
            color: 0, 1, 0, .8
        Button:
            text: 'Click me'
            on_press: root.on_press_button()
```

So, the code runs, but when I click the button, it gives me the following error:

`whatever_two.on_press_button() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the required argument in your `kv`:

```
    Button:
        text: 'Click me'
        on_press: root.on_press_button(self)
```